# Finding pairs of rows of dataframe by filtering rows based on difference between values of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes from which I need to find all pairs of s_key and t_key such that the difference between val1, val2 and val3 are under some specific thresholds.

For example, these are the two example dataframes.

```
  s_key   val1  val2  val3
0    c1  100.1  90.1   130
1    c2  100.5  89.5   128
2    c3   99.8  88.9   125

  t_key   val1  val2  val3
0    n1  100.0  90.3   135
1    n2   99.9  88.2   130
2    n3   99.5  85.0   127
```

Which can be created by the code:

```
s_data = [['c1', 100.1, 90.1, 130],['c2', 100.5, 89.5, 128],['c3', 99.8, 88.9, 125]]
s_df = pd.DataFrame(s_data,columns=['s_key','val1','val2','val3'])

t_data = [['n1', 100.0, 90.3, 135],['n2', 99.9, 88.2, 130],['n3', 99.5, 85.0, 127]]
t_df = pd.DataFrame(t_data,columns=['t_key','val1','val2','val3'])
```

I am taking thresholds for difference of val1, val2, val3 of the dataframes as 0.5, 1.5, 2.

So that the final dataframe after all the filtering will look like this:

```
  s_key t_key
0    c1    n1
1    c3    n1
2    c3    n2
```

Now the approach I am taking to solve this is not feasible for a large number of s_key and t_key. Original dataframe has several thousands of rows for both dataframes. So it is taking huge time to iterate over rows. Can this approach be made faster with vectorization?

```
res_df=pd.DataFrame()
for index,rows in s_df.iterrows():
    temp_df=t_df[['cellname','val2','val1','val3']].copy()
    temp_df['s_cell']=rows['cellname']
    temp_df['s_val1']=rows['val1']
    temp_df['s_val2']=rows['val2']
    temp_df['s_val3']=rows['val3']
    temp_df['diff1'] = temp_df['s_val1'] - rows['val1']
    temp_df=temp_df[temp_df['diff1']<0.5]
    temp_df['diff2'] = temp_df['s_val2'] - rows['val2']
    temp_df=temp_df[temp_df['diff2']<1.5]
    temp_df=temp_df[temp_df.apply(lambda x:filter_values(x['s_val3'],x['val3']),axis=1)]
    res_df=pd.concat([res_df,temp_df])
    del temp_df
```

Comment: good question.. just checking, why is 'c3 n3' combination not in the output? Because difference beween va1 of c3 and val 1 of n3 is .3 (99.8 - 99.5) which is under .5?

Comment: To come as an output pair, all three threshold conditions need to satisfy. Only pairs for which all three thresholds satisfy should come.

Comment: Ah ok.. gotit.. please see my solution below using `merge` and some slicing and conditional operations

Answer (score 1):

Please see this:

```
s_df['key'] = 1
t_df['key'] = 1
df = pd.merge(s_df, t_df,on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
df['val1diff'] = df.iloc[:,1] - df.iloc[:,5]
df['val2diff'] = df.iloc[:,2] - df.iloc[:,6]
df['val3diff'] = df.iloc[:,3] - df.iloc[:,7]
df = df[(df['val1diff'] < .5) & (df['val2diff'] < 1.5) & (df['val3diff'] < 2.0)]
df = df[['s_key', 't_key']].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  s_key t_key
0    c1    n1
1    c3    n1
2    c3    n2
```

Prints:

Comment: Hi. The solution works fine for smaller dataframes. But my dataframe has almost 40k and 20k rows. So the merged dataframe will have almost 800 mil rows. This takes too much memory and time. Is it possible to perform the filtering on each pair before merging the dataframes so that the dataframes will become smaller during merging?

Comment: Hmm.. tats right.. I will check if there is a better one

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code, have implemented the solution using Vectorisation. extracted val1,val2,val3 columns from the first dataframe. For each column, copied the values so that they 1st df - has mxn values. m- being the number of rows in the 1st df and n- being the number of rows in the second df. The second df will also be copied to create a mxn matrix. Now we can subtract the two matrixes to get the differences of val1. Repeat the same process for all other columns as well.

```
def func(val):
    a = s_df[val].to_numpy()
    a=np.array([a]*t_df.shape[0]).T
    b = t_df[val].to_numpy()
    b = np.array([b]*s_df.shape[0])
    return (a-b)
c1 = func('val1')
c2 = func('val2')
c3 = func('val3')
tf_array = np.where(c1 <0.5, np.where(c2 < 1.5,np.where(c2 < 2, 'True', 'False'), 'False'),'False')
my_index = np.where(tf_array == 'True')
dim1 = np.add(my_index[0],1)
dim2 = np.add(my_index[1],1)
d1 = np.char.add('c',dim1.astype(str))
d2= np.char.add('n',dim2.astype(str))
df_fin = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([d1,d2]))
df_fin.head()
```

I tested it with a fairly large dataset and it ran fine.
This code is based on the assumption that, In the first df the keys increment as c1,c2,...cm and the rows in the second df increment as n1,n2...nn. If you need just the indexes, please skip the last 6 lines (lines starting from dim1).

Comment: Hey, Did it work on your dataset? Just curious to know.

Comment: My dataset is pretty huge it seems for such an operation. Whereas most solutions work for datasets with around 1k-5k rows, my dataset has 30k-40k rows each. So the merged dataset will have around 800 mils rows, which is putting huge pressure on memory. Still trying to figure out an alternative approach if any, otherwise going for multiprocessing on each row. Also, the keys of my dataset don't increment in my case.